# react-native-fbsdk failed to compile in android

Tags: react-native, facebook, maven, build.gradle, react-native-fbsdk

I recently got the below issue when trying to run `yarn android` or `./gradlew app:assembleRelease`:

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve org.webkit:android-jsc:+.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Failed to list versions for org.webkit:android-jsc.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/webkit/android-jsc/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/webkit/android-jsc/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Read timed out
> Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[5.0,6.0[.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :react-native-fbsdk
> > Skipped due to earlier error
> Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5.0,6.0[.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :react-native-fbsdk
> > Skipped due to earlier error
> Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[5.0,6.0[.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :react-native-fbsdk
> > Skipped due to earlier error

Comment: https://jcenter.bintray.com is dead for a longer time...

Comment: Thanks, I got that, but didnt understand well, i'll try remove from my build gradle

Comment: Solution that worked to me instead of updating RN to 0.66:
in android/build.gradlew after each occurrence of `jcenter()` add `mavenCentral()` and in jitpack io url add just before `www.`, like maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' } instead of  like maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }